# HTML and CSS not working in Laravel Command

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am building a laravel application which among other functionalities, it will be used to generate registration certificates for a particular organization. I have designed the certificate using html and css and then I am converting the html to PDF by calling a routem the controller then view and the output PDF is okay.

What I want now is to create a laravel command, which will be generating the PDF from HTML and send them to the client via email.I have the command, it is generating the pdf file but css and images are not loaded in the output,it has only the text and image thumbnails but not properly formatted.

My challenge is how do i call the same logics in the Command and generate the HTML to PDF with the content properly styled and formatted??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please try inline CSS instead of using CSS in another file. Similarly, use JS in the same HTML/blade page.

Comment: you have to use direct images not in css

Comment: The custom css file is huge in such a way that i can't use them in inline css, i have tried to load them inside <style> tag, they are working except the images. I am also using bootstrap, the file also is huge, how can i load it in my file